# PHP Header error why does this not work?

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
require 'connection.php';

mysql_query("DELETE FROM quotes WHERE ID = $_GET[id]") or die("didnt delete properly");
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

When I run this it says:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at xxxxx on line 6

What is wrong?

Comment: Also, `$_GET[id]` concatenated unescaped into the query is a classic SQL injection. DANGER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `header.php` or `connection.php` are outputting some content.  You cannot modify the HTTP headers after content is sent, because the headers have already been sent at that point.

A hack of a solution would be this:

```
<?php

ob_start();

require 'header.php';
require 'connection.php';

mysql_query("DELETE FROM quotes WHERE ID = $_GET[id]") or die("didnt delete properly");

header('Location: index.php');

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

However, you should instead figure out where content is being sent and suppress it, or reorder it to come after the `header()` call.

If, as I suspect, `header.php` outputs an HTML header, you can just eliminate the `require 'header.php';` line -- the content will never be shown anyway, since this is a redirect.

Also, note that the HTTP standard *requires* that the value of a Location header be an absolute URL.  **Therefore, `header('Location: index.php');` will generate an HTTP response that is invalid according to the HTTP standard.**

Comment: I don't know how this is working, but it works!  Thank you :):):)

Answer (score 0):

Your php code is sending content from included files before header data from `header('Location: index.php')`. HTTP headers must always be sent prior to any other content.

And please for your own sake, use [parametrized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably echo/printing something out in `header.php` or your `die`  Which sends header information prior to your call for `header('Location: index.php');`

Answer (score 0):

The headers must be the first thing sent by your script. If there is any output to the page before you call the header() function then you will get that error.